# Basic results of error correcting codes

Tags: forward-error-correction, capacity

Please can someone verify these basic results about error correcting codes.

For this example I am using Reed-Solomon because there are functions to calculate the rate $r$ and distance $d$ of the code, which are

$$r = \frac{k}{n}$$
$$d = n - k + 1.$$

1.0 The rate and distance are independent for this code.

1.1 By introducing the parameter $c$, the rate can be changed without affecting the distance

$$r = \frac{k+c}{n+c}$$
$$d = n + c - k - c + 1 = n - k + 1.$$

1.2 The distance can be changed without affecting the rate

$$r = \frac{ck}{cn} = \frac{k}{n}$$
$$d = c(n - k) + 1.$$

I understand that there is nothing in these equations that prevents me from setting the rate higher than the channel capacity, but the proof of Shannon's noisy coding theorem is very complicated for me.

Am I on the right track with these ideas? Can you recommend any references to help me understand the capacity constraint?

Comment: No, you are not on the right track with these ideas. Statement 1.0 is false: $d = n(1-r) +1$ is very much a function of the rate, instead of being _independent_ of the rate (whatever that word _independent_ means to you).

Comment: @DilipSarwate do you not agree that the equations 1.1 and 1.2 are correct?

Comment: No, 1.2 is also false. $d$ remains at $n-k+1$ instead of increasing as you think it does.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The equation, the proof, says otherwise and I'm not convinced that you know what you're talking about. I could elaborate on 1.2 but I couldn't make it any clearer by putting it into words, except to benefit someone who doesn't understand the formula.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This question is too difficult. Let's look at 1.2 by itself https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63227/reed-solomon-code-with-different-distance-and-same-rate